# Nomenclature in swedish

Tags: nomenclature

As the headline says, how do I get the Nomenclatue headline in swedish? My code is as follows.

```
   \documentclass[10pt,oneside,swedish]{lips}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{nomencl} 
\usepackage[intoc, swedish]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}

\nomenclature{$a$}{Utökad temp.}
\nomenclature{c}{hej}
%Här skrivs variabler och beskrivning av dessa
\printnomenclature
\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

Comment: According to the documentation, the `nomencl` package only knows the following language options: `croatian,  danish,  english,  french,  german,  italian,  polish,  por-tuguese, russian, spanish, ukrainian`. If your question is about changing the title of the nomenclature, you could use the following in your preamble: `\renewcommand{\nomname}{new title}`

Comment: Okey, thanks!
Is there a way to make lines between the variable and the description?

Comment: What kind of lines? Horizontal ones or a verical one?

Comment: Sorry, horizontal ones such as: a.............."Descrition of..."

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your question, i'm kind of new to latex. lips is the the file where i do all my tabulars settings and then import it to my general file. Is that an answer good enough?